# unable to fetch the data form data array. What is the issue?

Tags: angular

My service code:

```
export class RecordService {

  constructor() { }

  getData(){
    return [
      {
        name : "Mim",
        online : true
      },
      {
        name : "ABC",
        online : false
      },
      {
        name : "XYZ",
        online : true
      },
      {
        name : "ABC",
        online : false
      },
      {
        name : "XYZ",
        online : true
      }
    ]
     
  }
}
```

app.component.ts code:

```
export class AppComponent {
  // text = 'intro2angular'
  data = {}

  constructor(private myFirstService : RecordService){

  }
  
  ngOninit(){
    this.data = this.myFirstService.getData()
  }
```

My app.component.html code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>S.no</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>isonline</td></tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let record of data; let i = index; let firstRecord = first; let lastRecord = last; let evenrecord = even; let oddrecord = odd" [ngClass]="{odd: oddrecord, even: evenrecord, first:firstRecord, last:lastRecord}">
    <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{record.name}}</td>
    <td>{{record.online}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Unable to fetch data from the data array. Gives error Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. What is the issue?

Another error gives:
ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 10, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the `data` as an empty array instead of an empty object.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  data = [];        // <-- array here

  constructor(private myFirstService : RecordService) { }

  ngOninit() {
    this.data = this.myFirstService.getData();
  }
  
  ...
}
```

When the component is rendered, before the `ngOnInit` is triggered, `data` variable holds an empty object instead of an array. `*ngFor` directive by default cannot loop over objects.

#### Update

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6jnaxy)

Comment: did data = [ ];  but the fetched data don't show in browser

Comment: @develop_code: What change detection strategy are you using?

Comment: I'm using angular and in the localhost not seeing any output table data

Comment: @develop_code: The [change detection mechanism](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/) in Angular decides when to re-render the template based on the changes in controller. Assuming you're using default mechanism, the new values pushed to `data` should be rendered. I've updated the answer to include a Stackblitz.

Comment: on Stackblitz the output is showing perfectly fine. What not in angular?

Comment: Then something else is interfering with the data. You need to more information about your implementation.